# Clean up directory after GCC make

Tags: git, gcc, makefile, commit

How can I clean up directory after compiling source codes with 'make', to do 'git commit'?

Or what you do when commiting git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be consciously committing changes, not just whatever the state of your directory is.  If you only commit what you intend to commit, the problem is moot.

I almost always use `git add -p` and actually pay attention to everything that's going into a change.  I change a *lot* of code throughout the day, and sometimes I'll go longer than I'd like without committing.  It's easy to split up all that work into a few commits before finishing it up.

That said, I *do* maintain a `.gitignore` and I quite often use `git clean` to wipe the directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a .gitignore file to ignore files when commiting:

http://help.github.com/git-ignore/

You can also create a 'clean' rule in your Makefile that would delete any files you don't want to commit.

Comment: Your gitignore should indeed ignore all build products. You should also never add those files before committing (a good reason not to use any variant on `git commit -A`, at least not without checking `git status` for untracked files). Once you've got everything you care about tracked, you can use `git clean <opts>` to remove everything untracked, which is often even more reliable than a `make clean`.